# Change WelcomePageView for DocumentSet using CSOM

Tags: document-set, pnp

We would like to change the WelcomePageView for a DocumentSet in SharePoint Online using CSOM C#, or PnP OfficeDev.

We are able to change the WelcomePageView for a DocumentSet using the web interface.

But when trying to do this through C# code, we noticed that the SchemaXml of the DocumentSet contenttype is readonly, and can't be set through C# code.

We found some code samples, but that only applies to Server Side Code.

Is it possible to do this through CSOM (Client Side Object) code ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing DocumentSet WelcomePageView using CSOM is not unfortunately supported.

Here's a UserVoice entry for this request and getting more votes for this, will have positive impact on the task prioritization in our internal process.